# Как сохранять и использовать части кода css (к примеру очистка стилей)?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Использую редактор  ATOM, но могу перейти на другой.

Comment: При чем тут какой редактор...?  Да любой.....  Что значит сохранять и использовать части кода? Не умеешь копировать или что?  И  что значит `к примеру очистка стилей`??? Ничего не понял

Comment: Я ожидал создания шаблона или импорт частей кода по определенным командам (<start css> - и создан шаблон)

Comment: От кого ожидал,, какого шаблона, по каким командам? Откуда импортировать, куда импортировать?   Тут ясновидящих нет...

Comment: Наверное вам нужно создать свой сниппет в редакторе.

Answer (score -1):

1. Перейдите на notepad++
2. скопируйте часть кода CSS в буфер обмена (выделить и нажать Ctrl+C)
3. создайте новый файл
4. вставьте скопированный код в него
5. сохраните новый файл в подходящей папке.

Вуаля! Вы сохранили требуемую часть кода CSS и можете теперь ее везде использовать - достаточно открыть файл, скопировать код и вставить куда нужно.

П.С. если это чересчур сложно - посмотрите в сторону директивы @import в CSS.

Comment: А минус-то за что? Ответ идеально соответствует вопросу.